# fragments sometimes overlap - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer and clicking on items shows/hides/creates full screen fragments.

For the most part, this code works great. But sometimes, maybe 1% of the time, I will get crazy full screen fragment overlapping when opening the app while it has already been running.

Is the problem with my code..? Or maybe something else in Android where it does not recognize I have the fragments with the tags already created?

Here is the relevant code for how I show/hide/create fragments:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Get to drawer layout so we can interact with it
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // Get the fragment manager to remove/add fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {

            // Hide visible fragment
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(getVisibleFragment()).commit();


            // Check if the fragment exists first.
            if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("profileFragment") != null) {

                // If the fragment exists, show it (no reason to recreate it).
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .show(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("profileFragment"))
                        .commit();
            } else {
                // If the fragment does not exist, add it to fragment manager with a tag to identify it.

                // Create new fragment instance with required argument(s).
                ProfileFragment fragment = ProfileFragment.newInstance();

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "profileFragment")
                        .commit();
            }

            // Set the title
            mToolbarTitleTextView.setText(R.string.title_activity_profile);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_feed) {

            // Hide visible fragment
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(getVisibleFragment()).commit();


            // Check if the fragment exists first.
            if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("feedFragment") != null) {
                // If the fragment exists, show it (no reason to recreate it).
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .show(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("feedFragment"))
                        .commit();
            } else {
                // If the fragment does not exist, add it to fragment manager with a tag to identify it.
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.content_frame, new feedFragment(), "feedFragment")
                        .commit();
            }

            // Set the title
            mToolbarTitleTextView.setText(R.string.title_activity_feed);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_notifications) {

            // Hide visible fragment
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(getVisibleFragment()).commit();

            // Hide the post button
            mPostButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Check if the fragment exists first.
            if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("notificationsFragment") != null) {
                // If the fragment exists, show it (no reason to recreate it).
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .show(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("notificationsFragment"))
                        .commit();
            } else {
                // If the fragment does not exist, add it to fragment manager with a tag to identify it.
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.content_frame, new NotificationsFragment(), "notificationsFragment")
                        .commit();
            }

            // Set the title
            mToolbarTitleTextView.setText(R.string.title_activity_notifications);

        }

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    // Useful method to hide the currently visible fragment
    public Fragment getVisibleFragment(){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
        if(fragments != null){
            for(Fragment fragment : fragments){
                if(fragment != null && fragment.isVisible())
                    return fragment;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

EDIT: It is really hard to reproduce this error which makes it hard to debug. It seems to randomly happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem. In my MainActivity I did this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Basically what was happening is if I had 1+ fragments on the screen, if the android system ran low on resources while the app was in the background and shut it down, when restored, `MainActivity.onCreate()` would be called and it would re-instantiate all the fragments with the call

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

So I just made it null and this prevents from all those fragments to be recreated.

The reason they are overlapping is because they were all getting shown at once.

Definitely not the correct way to do it, but it solves my problem right now =P

Answer (score 1):

Why hide and keep all the fragments with `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add();` you can avoid this error by keeping only one fragment in memory and avoiding the hassle of hiding fragments by using `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace()` and using the fragment lifecycle methods to store the fragment state if necessary.

Comment: I was using `replace()` before. You are right, I could use lifecycle methods to store fragment state (more hassle). Are you saying this is a memory issue..?

Comment: By using `FragmentTransaction.add()`, you're creating a stack of fragments and displaying only the one on top (which you later change by using `show()` or `hide()` respectively. Whereas `FragmentTransaction.replace()` keeps only one fragment at a time. You can avoid fragment overlapping by just having one instance of a fragment active at a time.